# How many miners can i have with 65kw

Tags: mining

i want to know how many miners can i have with 65kw provided by solar panels, the average of the miners is 1200w 100-250v 47-64Hz.

Comment: You mention the average power consumption but the peak power consumption of each miner is probably more relevant. Do you know what that happens to be?

Comment: i dont know, the recommend psu is 1149w to run the miner

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the answer is simply to take the total power and divide it with the peak power that each miner can consume. In your case:

65.000 / 1200 = 54.12 ~= 54.

So I would say that the maximum number of miners in this setup is 54.

Comment: But this only applies when your solar panels are producing electricity at full capacity. If it is cloudy or the sun is low in the sky, the number will be lower.

Comment: What is a good number ? 49~= ?

Comment: That depends how much power you expect the solar panels to produce. Jsut because their capacity is 65kW, does not mean that they will produce that whenever the sun is up. It depends on where they are located. And obviously the miners will not be able to run at night if you have not invested in a bunch of batteries (which I would not recommend -- too expensive). 

So you have to find out how much power the panels can produce and take it from there. If you want more information about the solar panels, try this forum instead: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power